# What does using Redis for pub-sub means

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I was listening to a tech talk and the speaker mentioned that they used Reddis for pub-sub. I was wondering what pub-sub is and how Redis fits in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly this: http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Comment: BTW is your internet provider/national government blocking access to google.com and other major search engines?